# jOOQ can't auto generate classes

Tags: maven, jsp, jooq

I'm trying to auto generate the jOOQ java code for my MySql database, but it's not working. I'm using jOOQ for my JSP project from maven.

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyHomeProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyHomeProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>13</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-mysql</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myprojectdb?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</url>
                                <user>webuser</user>
                                <password>webuserP@$$*oR6</password>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <database>
                                    <name>org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
                                    <excludes></excludes>
                                    <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                                </database>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>com.myproject.home.jooq</packageName>
                                    <directory>${basedir}\src</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.0.13</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- MySQL -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>mysql</groupId>
             <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <version>8.0.13</version>
         </dependency>
        <!-- jOOQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Other dependencies here -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm running this project on eclipse with Tomcat. When I want to run the web application, I clean the project, then Project>properties>Deployment Assembly>Add>Java Build Path Entries>Maven Dependencies.

When I run the project, no java code for database is generated.
As it says in the [documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/code-generation/codegen-maven/), since I'm using maven with jOOQ, I can auto generate the JAVA code without need to use cli. And without the need to create a `library.xml` file.

My issue is that jOOQ doesn't auto generate JAVA files with this `pom.xml` file. What am I doing wrong? Is there another configurations I need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified:

```xml
<inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
```

MySQL doesn't have such a schema by default. Please use the schema of your actual database instead (case sensitive), or omit the inputSchema to generate code for all schemas.

Comment: I omitted `inputSchema`. Now when I clean and build the project, I can see `com.myproject.home.jooq` package generated under the `src` directory next to my other packages. But I can't import tables from that package into my code: `the import com.myproject.home.jooq.ANYTHING cannot be resolved`

Comment: I had to refresh the `src` directory. Now it's working, Thanks.